# How to achieve "spherical" mapping in procedural materials?

Tags: materials, node-editor, procedural, vector-mapping

What I have:

[image]

What I would want (sorry for a terrible sketch):

[image]

How to convert object/generated coordinates in such way?

Comment: the answer is here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44292/procedural-texture-for-longitudinal-lines

Comment: @moonboots Thank you, it works well :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want the longitudes, the answers linked by @moonboots will suffice.. if you want to map a 2D procedural texture to a sphere, this sort of setup will do the Y dimension (latitudes) as well..

[image]