# Can't create a specific displacement based on voronoi texture

Tags: texturing, shaders, displacement

I'm just messing around with shaders and I can't create an object I have in mind. I have this cube (with subsurface level of 4) and this voronoi texture.

[image]

The look I'm trying to achieve is to displace the individual cells, so I get some kind of a jaggedy sphere that exactly matches the cells of texture.
I've tried something like this
[image]

But this doesn't work as I thought it would

[image]

The problem here that there are multiple colors on one "extruded" column where I'd like to have just one color. Is it possible to achieve this? I'm sorry if it's a noob question, but I'm trying to see what's possible to do with shaders and if I'm expecting too much :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To save too much strain on the GPU, you may want to separate the business of displacing faces and coloring them, to give the renderer some geometry to work with in the cracks.

You could make a displacement map based on Distance From Edge, shown on the left, below, and a sparate parallel Voronoi to color the displaced faces.

[image]

This is a 2D Voronoi, mapped to the surface of the sphere as described [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/202617/35559), but the principle would be the same for other cell-like textures

[image]

Comment: You've given me a lot of material to research and a lot of advice, I really appreciate it! I'll try to recreate this by myself and adjust it to my ideas!

Answer (score 1):

needs more geometry. you have a mesh made of squares like pixels in a bitmap, and you are overlaying shapes like vector images
your output is now defined by the resolution of your bitmap
aka, the number of subdivisions on your mesh.

My computer cried and fell in a heap before I could make this look good.

Comment: Ah, I see, that's too bad. Do you know what I could research to achieve this kind of look? Or is modeling this shape my only option?

Comment: i think yr gonna have to have the mesh match the texture. there may be a short way to achieve that tho, which i am currently ignorant of

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot for the help!